# Get info from WMS layer with OpenLayers mobile jQuery?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, mobile, jquery

How to do a GetFeatureInfo request on a WMS layer (GeoServer)?

I am using OpenLayers jQuery mobile. I've already called the WMS in jQuery mobile, but how to get feature information when clicking the attribute.

Comment: May be this can help. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113616/display-data-from-geoserver-on-click-map-with-openlayers/114171#114171

Comment: WMS does not supply Feature info, that is WFS, you may want to do a little more research on this site and re-ask your question ..

Comment: For sure WMS supports GetFeatureInfo. See the syntax of the request from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html.

Comment: thanks for reply, im use jquery mobile openlayer, the framecloud that have in openlayer function not support jquery mobile openlayer, how i want to solve that

Comment: @user30184 I stand corrected, I thought it passed the call to WFS. For posterity, from the manual .. `The WMS GetFeatureInfo operation requests the spatial and attribute data for the features at a given location on a map. It is similar to the WFS GetFeature operation, but less flexible in both input and output. Since GeoServer provides a WFS service we recommend using it instead of GetFeatureInfo whenever possible.`